# Please improve "Related Questions"

Tags: feature-request, related-questions

As others have noted, the "Related Questions" are so seldom *actually related*. In the past it was easier to just ignore, but now that section is featured prominently below questions without answers. For me it's really distracting and at first glance almost looks like an answer. This would be a bit less troubling if the results weren't so tragically off-topic.

Are we still using Elasticsearch for this? Could now be a good time to revisit the way results are compiled and possibly improve things?

Comment: "*others*", you mean "*everybody*"...!?

Comment: Apparently *all* php now questions are now related to "How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?"